# How to remove year dropdown from ui-datepicker Magento 2

Tags: magento2, datepicker, calendar

How can i remove `ui-datepicker-year` from calender in Magento 2.
I only want to make user select only date and month.
How to achieve that.

I have removed this line of code from `jquery-ui.js`

```
if ( !inst.yearshtml ) {
        inst.yearshtml = "";
        if (secondary || !changeYear) {
            html += "<span class='ui-datepicker-year'>" + drawYear + "</span>";
        } else {
            // determine range of years to display
            years = this._get(inst, "yearRange").split(":");
            thisYear = new Date().getFullYear();
            determineYear = function(value) {
                var year = (value.match(/c[+\-].*/) ? drawYear + parseInt(value.substring(1), 10) :
                    (value.match(/[+\-].*/) ? thisYear + parseInt(value, 10) :
                    parseInt(value, 10)));
                return (isNaN(year) ? thisYear : year);
            };
            year = determineYear(years[0]);
            endYear = Math.max(year, determineYear(years[1] || ""));
            year = (minDate ? Math.max(year, minDate.getFullYear()) : year);
            endYear = (maxDate ? Math.min(endYear, maxDate.getFullYear()) : endYear);
            inst.yearshtml += "<select class='ui-datepicker-year' data-handler='selectYear' data-event='change'>";
            for (; year <= endYear; year++) {
                inst.yearshtml += "<option value='" + year + "'" +
                    (year === drawYear ? " selected='selected'" : "") +
                    ">" + year + "</option>";
            }
            inst.yearshtml += "</select>";

            html += inst.yearshtml;
            inst.yearshtml = null;
        }
    }
```

So the year dropdown is removed but still when i select date and month, it shows year in the textbox.

[image]

How to remove date from text box.

Comment: can you add code and output?

Comment: @magefms updated

Comment: you display it in phtml file?

Comment: @magefms Yes its in phtml

Comment: did you try hiding it on jquery, the same like this `$(".ui-datepicker-year").hide();`

Comment: @magefms This will hide the year dropdown, but when we select date and month it will append year automatically on the textbox

Comment: did you try answer below?

Comment: @magefms yes didnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93289/discussion-between-magefms-and-summu).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your **phtml** file:

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui'
    ], function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#datepicker").datepicker({
           dateFormat: 'MM dd'
           });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note: where **`"#datepicker"`** is the id of your datetime picker input element